# Get Month of the date in Hive and group by department

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

i have three columns StartDate,Department,Tripduration(StartDate Column is in "MM/dd/yyyy" need to be converted "yyyy-MM-dd")

> The requirement is to query the data for each month & grouped by the department

Any help would be appreciated?

Answer (score 1):

you can convert "MM/dd/yyyy" to "yyyy-MM-dd" this way.

```
select TO_DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(StartDate, 'dd/MM/yyyy'))) as month
from your_table;
```

and group by (month & department)

```
select 
  MONTH(TO_DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(StartDate, 'dd/MM/yyyy')))) as month,
  Department,
  sum(Tripduration) --or avg or whatever you want
from your_table
group by MONTH(TO_DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(StartDate, 'dd/MM/yyyy')))), Department;
```